# DIV height dynamic with scroll overflow

Tags: css, html

I have a wrapper div that has height 100% of the page, within the wrapper I have a dynamic number of divs.
I want the last div in the wrapper div to fill the remaining space.

```
  html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px #FF0;
}
#wrapper .child {
    border: solid 1px #F00;
    height: 40px;
}
#wrapper .last {
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

As you can see in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/CCDHT/ when I set the last div height to 100% it overflows the wrapper div.

this is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described clearly looks like a `<table>`. You may attempt to emulate it:

1. Add `display: table;` to `#wrapper`
2. Add `display: table-row;` to `#wrapper div`

http://jsfiddle.net/WCx4P/1/

The cons of this solution are:

- last div must have a content
- you cannot use borders on all `#wrapper div` directly

It is a nasty solution, but the only one I can think of right now.

I would rather take a look at the exact design you're trying to achieve and find a better workaround for your problem.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using as it didn't require JS. Here is my updated script http://jsfiddle.net/CCDHT/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
overflow:auto;
```

to the main div.

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/CCDHT/2/

Comment: I only want the Last div to have scrollable content, not the main wrapper. This is the solution I ended up using http://jsfiddle.net/CCDHT/4/ . But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CCDHT/1/

Setting

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
...
```

achieves your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

set it as a `inline-block` with `overflow:scroll;` and remove the `height`.

```
#wrapper{

    display:inline-block;
    overflow:scroll;

}
```

`inline-block` takes up all the space it needs (as much as it can).

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a simple jQuery function to run on the page initialization to get this kind of functionality:

```
function set_div_height() {

    el_height = (
        ($(window).height()) - ($('.div1').height() + $('.div2').height())
    );
    $('.div3').height(el_height); 

}
```

Comment: You forget the borders :-)

Comment: Interesting... jQuery doesn't account for that when getting element height? How would I programmatically account for them?

Comment: You will need to watch it when calculating heights. After all, a pixel can render a scrollbar. I usually calculate them in staticly, meaning `2px` for 1 div in this case.
See [here](http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-height-innerheight-and-outerheight/) for more on the height topic.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it dynamically, since you want to adapt between different screens. I would us jQuery to achieve this.
Be careful with the body margin and borders.

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
}

  $(document).ready(function () {
      div3_height = $(window).height() - ($(".child").outerHeight(true) * 2);
      $("#wrapper .last").css("height", div3_height - 4);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/CCDHT/5/